# Hard Time with 2-D Array For-Loop Syntax

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have a bit of code shown below, I understand what it is doing but I don't understand part of the syntax. I was wondering if someone could explain it to me. Basically, the code is filling a 2D Array with arrays of randoms integers between 0 and 2. What I don't get is, why do I put "result[i][j]" below after the second for loop. Why don't I just put result[j] instead. I found the code online and knew what it did, but again, I didn't understand that bit of syntax.

```
    function buildArray(width, height){
    var result= [];

    for (var i = 0 ; i < width; i++) {

        result[i] = [];

        for (var j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            result[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
            console.log(result[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you pass into the function a `width` and `height` value of 3...

```
buildArray(3, 3);
```

You can think of the `width` value as representing the number of 'column' and the `height` value as representing the number of 'items' in each column.

In the first iteration of the first for-loop the `result` has one column.  Because `i` is zero at this time we can say...

```
result[0] = new Array();
```

The array is empty, but then the second for-loop comes into play.

The second for-loop populates that newly invoked array, in this example with 3 randomly generated integers.

Let's say that the first iteration of the second for-loop produces the integer '2', the second iteration produces '0', and the third '1'.  That would mean that `resutl[0]` now looks like this...

```
result[0] = [2, 0, 1];
```

...so that...

```
result[0][0] = 2;
result[0][1] = 0;
result[0][2] = 1;
```

Then `i` is incremented, and new array at position `result[1]` is invoked, and then that is populated with 3 items. Etc etc.

The value in the second bracket in `result` indicates the index-position of the value in the 'height' array, which is itself indicated by the index-position in the `result` array's first bracket.

By the end of the example `result` will be an array of `length = 3` (three arrays), each containing three randomly generated integers.

Try replacing the `console.log()` with something like this...

```
console.log('result['+i+']['+j+'] = ' + result[i][j]);
```

...to get a better idea of the index-positions of the random numbers being generated.

Also you might like to heck out : [Creating a custom two-dimensional Array @ javascriptkit.com](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/twoarray1.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

2d array has 2 reference point think of it as table i represent its row and J its column , the syntax simply tells the program that that value to be stored should be at i'th row and j'th column , if you don't provide i'th position it will not recognise row to be considered 
hope this helps :)

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Lets debug it :)

```
function buildArray(width, height){
    var result= []; // declared a 1-D array

    for (var i = 0 ; i < width; i++) {

        result[i] = [];   // create another array inside the 1-D array. 
                          // result[0] = [];

          for (var j = 0; j < height; j++) {

           result[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); // result[0][0] = some random number
           console.log(result[i][j]);
        }

    }
    return result;
}
```

Coming to your doubt :

> why do I put `result[i][j]` below after the second for loop. Why don't I just put `result[j]` instead.

If you want to do in that way you have to bit modify the code. See the below code for reference

```
function buildArray(width, height){
    var result= []; // declared a 1-D array

    for (var i = 0 ; i < width; i++) {

      // result[i] = [];    not required                              
        var my_array = [];   // you need to define a new array
        for (var j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            my_array[j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); // fill your new array with random numbers
           //console.log(result[i][j]);   not required
        }
     result.push(my_array);  // you need to push your array into results
    }
    return result;
}
```